# Boto3:describe_auto_scaling_groups giving Unknown parameter in input: "Filters" error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, autoscaling

I'm trying to list a filtered set of ASGs based on Tag value like this:

```
client = boto3.client('autoscaling',region)
asg=client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
        Filters=[
                {"Name": "tag:ecs_cluster", "Values": ["testCluster"]},
                {"Name": "tag:cluster-name", "Values": ["ciCluster"]}
            ])
```

This is inline with the Boto3 [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_auto_scaling_groups) but on execution it gives the following error:

```
Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in input: "Filters", must be one of: AutoScalingGroupNames, NextToken, MaxRecords
```

How do I get a filtered list without giving any AutoScalingGroupNames?

Comment: What version of boto3 are you using?

Comment: This is run via AWS lambda

Comment: boto3 in lambda is incomplete. You have to bundle your own boto3 if you are using python 3.9 lambda and still does not work?

Comment: If I don't pass the Filter parameter and just run client.describe_auto_scaling_groups() it does return values. So it's not like the method doesn't exist. Still can't wrap my head around why it would need me to upload the binaries as well. It anyhow runs on Amazon Linux 2 box at the backend.

Comment: boto3 in lambda is not the same as on  Amazon Linux 2. Some options are not available. You found one of them.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, when a lambda is run, even though it is built on Amazon Linux 2, boto3 binaries are still a bit different than what I would get incase it was a pip installation? is there any documentation I can read on this? Also, really appreciate your input.

Comment: Sadly, there is no documentation on that. Could be AWS lambda bug or some optimization feature. I don't know why it is this way.

Comment: This indeed is a bug, thanks for nudging me in the right direction. I've logged it with AWS and will update the thread once it's resolved.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Hopefully they will solve that permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stuck with this issue :

"Filters" option is a new feature recently introduced. This currently work on latest AWS CLI, I tested as well with latest version and I could confirm it was working.

Working version:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.4.0 Python/3.8.8 Darwin/19.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

Other services are still being updated and there is no ETA on when it will be available across all platforms. You may use current version of AWS CLI while Lambda is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am having exactly the same error you mention, working fine in a local script but not in lambda,  but I would say the real guilty of "filter" not to work is the botocore version on lambda.

This is the part of the code working fine on local script but NOT working on Lambda:

```
response = asg.describe_auto_scaling_groups(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Patch Group','Values': ['asg',]},],MaxRecords=100)
```

I did print out the boto3 and botocore versions of Lambda:

```
print(boto3.__version__)
print(botocore.__version__)
```

And I did install the same versions locally and I am able to reproduce the same lambda error locally

```
pip install boto3==1.18.55
pip3 install botocore==1.21.55
```

Following [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-runtime-errors/),  I am doubting if I should upload my own python + botocore + boto3 layer or if I should work on the code to make it work with Lambda's default boto3 + botocore versions.

By the way, these are the versions which with it works:

- aws-cli/2.3.6 Python/3.8.8 Linux/5.13.0-27-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off
- Python 3.8.10
- boto3 Version: 1.20.26
- botocore Version: 1.21.65

This [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) with Lambda runtimes is helpful as well.

Best regards